# Why won't my controller just hand back the model unchanged?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have had this problem before and it annoys the hell out of my but I just cannot for the life of me remember what the problem was.

I have a controller...

```
public ActionResult SubmitApplication(ApplicationModel model)
{
   return View("Index", model);
}
```

And the view

```
@model ApplicationModel 
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { action = "/apply/SubmitApplication" }))

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)

    <input type="submit" text="submit"/>

}
```

I stick a break on the action method and the email entered is being passed to the action method no problem. BUT.....No matter what happens the controller clears the email down at some point I end up with an empty email box when its delivered to the page. But I want to preserve it so the user doesn't HAVE to enter ALL of the information again. What am I missing here?

Thanks

EDIT:

Sorry guys I had a faulty watermarking tool that was masking the response, however there is a still a strange problem.....When I do....

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Apply(ApplicationModel model)
{
    return View("Index",new ApplicationModel(){FullName = "newValue"});

}
```

Instead of getting the "newValue" on the page, I still get the original posted value. Can anybody explain this? Is is to do with model state?

Comment: TextBoxFor takes its value from ModelState (unfortunately). Look what's there.

Comment: Can you add the HttpGet or HttpPost method of your controller on your question ? One of them missing, and could help us to solved your question

Comment: maybe it's cached? put this attribute on action `[OutputCache(Duration=0)]`

Answer (score 1):

The view helpers check, if there is a matching item in the model state and use this value if it exists. This value is in most cases the value the user typed before posting. If you want to force the view helpers to use your passed model you should clear the model state.